# Is a many-field index on a large table a good idea?

Tags: sql, database-design, indexing

I never designed a big database before so I never cared about indexes. However, now I am working on a large project which require large size database. So I am identifying each table that I will be using it on inner join as index.

Just as an example one of the large tables has fields like this:

```
Userid
Industryid
Teamid
Zoneid
```

Anything with I'd is a identification to point to a second table. So I have indexed those.

This table has 60 fields but 16 of those are indexed + 1 primary field.

If this a good idea to have such a large table with all these indexes? I am expecting this table to be over 4 million records with in 1 year.. The reason why I done such a thing is to is to make is easier and faster to do inner join between this table with the other tables

What is the best way to use indexes in such a large project?

Comment: All the four fields look like they could be foreign keys. And the four combined *could* be a natural primary key. I cannot tell about the other 12 indices, but a table with 60 fields and 12 indices looks a bit suspicious, wrt the data model.

Comment: actually 12 of those are foreign keys and 4 are searchable. so for eaxample I have userid and also username eventhough i have user name is a second table called uses. and i am not sure if i did the right call here but this will eleminate 1 inner join on such a large table. plus it keeps the user name in the history even if the user name was changed for any reason.

Comment: Having a single table with 16 FK's is either a violation of 3NF/BCNF or a work of art. Denormalisation to avoid (inner) joins sounds like a bad habit from the past, IMnsHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This table has 60 fields but 16 of those are indexed + 1 primary field.

This *looks* a bit excessive, but if you really need all these indexes then it's OK.

Indexes are not free: each additional index will take space, and require maintenance<sup>1</sup> when modifying data, in return to speed-up when searching for data (assuming it's used correctly). It's up to you to identify the right trade-off for you particular case.

> If this a good idea to have such a large table with all these indexes?

Having indexes on FKs is almost always a good idea, so the DBMS can maintain the FKs with good performance. Specifically, whenever a parent row is deleted or the referenced key updated, the DBMS has to search for the child rows. Theoretically, if you never delete/update parent, you won't really need indexes on FKs either, although some DBMSes will force you to have them in any case.

These indexes *can* be (and usually are) useful for JOINins, but that really depends on *how* you JOIN and how capable is the query planner of you DBMS.<sup>2</sup>

> What is the best way to use indexes in such a large project?

For each performance-sensitive query, carefully examine the query execution plan and measure the actual timing on **representative amounts of data**. Just because a query is executed one way on a small table, [doesn't mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14718958/533120) it will be executed the same way when the table grows.

And last but not least, I warmly recommend reading [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/)

---

*<sup>1</sup> Every time a row is inserted into table, the DBMS has to insert the corresponding key in the index B-tree. When the row is removed, the key is removed from the index. When an indexed field is updated, the old key needs to be removed and the new one inserted. The more indexes you have on your table, the more time the DBMS will have to spend doing this "index maintenance" whenever you INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE a row in that table.*

*<sup>2</sup> There are many ways a JOIN can be executed: nested loops in various orders, merge joins, hash joins... Different strategies may require different indexes or even different **kinds** of indexes (e.g. a B-tree won't do much good for hash joins). Not all DBMSes are capable of using all these strategies nor using existing indexes in all cases when they could theoretically be used. So an indexing strategy that works well for one DBMS may not necessarily work as well for another. And sometimes, you can keep the indexes, but you have to "nudge" the DBMS in the right direction, either by using "query hints" or by using a syntax that is "friendly" towards the query optimizer of the particular DBMS, even though the equivalent but more human-readable syntax may exist. For example, older versions of MySQL would always execute an IN sub-query as the inner one of the nested loops, even in cases where a reverse order of loops or a merge join would be faster. That's why people often recommend [rewriting IN as JOIN](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/03/25/mysql-in-query-performance/) under MySQL (though I hear they fixed that in MySQL 5.6). OTOH, rewriting an IN as JOIN under Oracle is not very useful, since Oracle is much better at executing equivalent queries equivalently, even when there are syntactic differences.*

Comment: Thanks you for such a good feedback. When you say indexes are not free and require maintenace, what exactly did you mean? what kind of maitenance required? what you mean "how capable is the query planner of you DBMS."  Thanks for the tips :)

Comment: Branko, Thank you so much for your help this made it much more clear for me :)