# Performance gains vs Normalizing your tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, normalization

Ok ok I know you probably all going to kill me for asking this, however I got into an friendly programmer argument with a co-worker about one of our database tables and he asked a question which I know the answer to but I couldn't explain it is the better way.

I will simplify the situation for the simplicity of the question, We have a fairly large table of people / users. Now amongst other data being stored the data in question is as follows: we have a simNumber, cellNumber and the ipAddress of that sim.

Now I am saying that we should make a table lets call it SimTable and put those 3 entries in the sim table, and then put a FK in the UsersTable linking the two. Why? Because that's what I have always been taught NORMALISE your tables!!! Ok so all is good in that regard.

But now my friend says to me yes, but now when you want to query a users phone number, SQL now has to go and:

1. search for the user
2. search for the sim fk
3. search for the correct sim row in the sim database
4. get the phone number

Now when I go and request 10000 users phone numbers, the number of operations done seriously grows in size.

Vs the other approach

1. search for the user
2. find the phone number

Now the argument is purely performance based. As much as I understand why we do normalize the data (to remove redundant data, maintainability, make changes to data in one table which propagate up etc.. ) It does appear to me that the approach with the data in one table will be faster or will at least less tasks/ operations to give me the data I want?

So what is the case in this situation? I do hope that I have not asked anything insanely silly , it is early in the morning so do forgive me if im not thinking clearly

The technology involved in MS SQL server 2012

[EDIT]
This article below also touches on some pf the concepts I have mentioned above
http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/Should-I-Normalize-My-Database.htm

Comment: You can get even better performance if you pretend that everyone actually has the same phone number and don't even bother storing it. It's easy to be fast and *wrong*.

Comment: If the only reason you normalize is that you were taught to always normalize, then it's no wonder you are at a loss for how to convince a colleague, especially a programmer.  There are reasons why each normalization form (1NF, 2NF, 3NF, BCNF, 4NF, 5NF...) were favored once they were discovered.  There are also trade offs between ultimate normalization and some other design.  Once you know the trade offs, you'll be in a better situation to make the case for your design.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The goal of normalization is not performance. The goal is to model your data correctly with minimum redundancy so you avoid data anomalies.

Say for example two users share the same phone. If you store the phones in the user table, you'd have sim number, IP address, and cell number stored one each user's row.

Then you change the IP address on one row but not the other. How can one sim number have two IP addresses? Is that even valid? Which one is correct? How would you fix such discrepancies? How would you even detect them?

There are times when denormalization is worthwhile, if you really need to optimize data access for one query that you run very frequently. But denormalization comes at a cost, so be prepared to commit yourself to a lot more manual work to take responsibility for data integrity. More code, more testing, more cleanup tasks. Do those count when considering "performance" of the project overall?

---

Re comments:

I agree with @JoelBrown, as soon as you implement your first case of denormalization, you compromise on data integrity.

I'll expand on what Joel mentions as "well-considered." Denormalization benefits *specific* queries. So you need to know which queries you have in your app, and which ones you need to optimize for. Do this conservatively, because while denormalization can help a specific query, it *harms* performance for all other uses of the same data. So you need to know whether you need to query the data in different ways.

Example: suppose you are designing a database for StackOverflow, and you want to support tags for questions. Each question can have a number of tags, and each tag can apply to many questions. The normalized way to design this is to create a third table, pairing questions with tags. That's the physical data model for a many-to-many relationship:

```
Questions ----<- QuestionsTagged ->---- Tags
```

But you figure you don't want to do the join to get tags for a given question, so you put tags into a comma-separated string in the questions table. This makes it quicker to query a given question and its associated tags.

But what if you also want to query for one specific tag and find its related questions? If you use the normalized design, it's simply a query against the many-to-many table, but on the `tag` column.

But if you denormalize by storing tags as a comma-separated list in the Questions table, you'd have to search for tags as substrings within that comma-separated list. Searching for substrings can't be indexed with a standard B-tree style index, and therefore searching for related questions becomes a costly table-scan. It's also more complex and inefficient to insert and delete a tag, or to apply constraints like uniqueness or foreign keys.

That's what I mean by denormalization making an improvement for one type of query *at the expense of other uses of the data*. That's why it's a good idea to start out with everything in normal form, and then refactor to denormalized designs later on a case by case basis as your bottlenecks reveal themselves.

This goes back to old wisdom:

> "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" -- [Donald Knuth](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil/)

In other words, don't denormalize until you can demonstrate during load testing that (a) it makes a real improvement to performance that justifies the loss of data integrity, and (b) it does not degrade performance of other cases unacceptably.

Comment: So basically, the summary of what you are saying is, denormalizing is faster and better for performance, but you loose on data integrity. So the goal is to denormalize as far as possible without loosing data integrity.

Comment: @Zapnologica - You can't denormalize without risking a loss of data integrity.  This is how the normal forms are defined.  The goal is to normalize your tables and then make well considered choices about denormalization if this becomes the best way to deal with _actual_ performance problems that you discover in real world load testing.  The first goal should be keep the data right.  Fast is pointless if the data is wrong.  Also don't assume that RDBMS won't be fast with normalized data.  It's what they're built to do.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already understand the benefits of normalisation, so I won't cover these.

There are a couple of considerations here:
1. Does a user always have one and only phone number?
If so, then it is still normalised to add these to the user table. However, if the user can have either no phone number or multiple phone numbers, then the phone details should be held in a seperate table.

1. Assuming you have these in seperate tables, but after conducting performance tests you found that joining on these 2 tables was having a significant effect on performance, then you may choose to deliberately denormalise the tables for performance gains.

Comment: I disagree.  What the OP said was that he normalizes because he was taught to always normalize.  I take that to mean that he wasn't taught the benefits and the trade-offs.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already provided some good points and you may also want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24475307/533120).

I'd just like to mention one more aspect that is often overlooked: I/O tends to be the greatest component of the cost of most queries, and denormalization generally increases the storage size of data, therefore making the DBMS cache "smaller".

If your normalized database fits into cache and denormalized doesn't, you may actually observe a performance *decrease* for the latter.

And you won't be able to spot that in development, unless you actually have the amount of data that is similar to production. This is one of many reasons why you should never, ever denormalize without solid measurements (on representative amounts of data) to justify it.