# DB design advice wanted

Tags: mysql, sql, database, facebook, database-design

I am looking for some advice on a design I'm working at. This is the case :

I got a database with a meeting table and a user table. Each meeting has a organisor, which corresponds to the ID of a user in the usertable. Verry simple at this point.

Now through the facebook api I get a list of friends from each person. I want to search my database for meetings organised by my friends. The first thing I thought of was just a simple IN('list of friends') in the query, but I can imagine this is killing the performance.

The idea now is to make an extra table containing a userID and a friendID and joining that in the query.

Does somebody has some advice on what performs best. Other solutions are, ofcourse, more than welcome ;)

thx

N

PS. MySQL DB

Comment: "but I can imagine this is killing the performance." --- is it just imagination or knowledge?

Comment: Well, I know an IN statement is often rewritten by the DB to a bunch of OR statements, so in my imagination this is not a good thing for performance. Thats why I ask for advice here, I don't know for sure ;)

Comment: With performance questions usually the best (or only) way to tell for sure is to test it both ways under realistic production loads and see what happens.  Database query optimizers are very complex and it can be hard to predict what they will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IN` is not a fundamental problem here. But it can be a practical problem if the given DBMS's optimizer is not very good and cannot produce optimal query plan. But in that case you can usually rewrite your query to use a different syntax (e.g. `JOIN`) that accomplishes the same but allows the optimizer to produce a better plan.

MySQL was notorious for not optimizing `INs` well, so people tended to use `JOIN` by default. Other DBMSes typically don't have such limitations. It's best to test performance yourself, [on representative amounts of data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14718958/533120), to see whether you actually have a problem or not.

BTW, you'll need a junction table between meetings and users anyway - what's the purpose of a meeting if it cannot have multiple participants, after all? And if organizer should also be considered a participant, you can do something like this:

[image]