# Join 10 tables on a single join id called session_id that's stored in session table. Is this good/bad practice?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

There's 10 tables all with a session_id column and a single session table.   The goal is to join them all on the session table. I get the feeling that this is a major code smell. Is this good/bad practice ?
What problems could occur?

Comment: Your boss says joining many tables is a common table design? I say he's nuts... and your database schema seems quite badly designed with all those session ids being stored in so many tables.

Comment: In general if you have 10 tables with common ID and each table carries a specific domain of normalised data then thats perfectly fine.  If you need a query to return data from all 10 tables then you need 10 joins, thats fine too.

Comment: It's an unusual approach. If pursued, it would be more normal/logical? to first UNION all those tables and then JOIN that as a subquery onto the session table.

Comment: Too much hand-waving.  Please show us the schema (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`) and `SELECT` for each approach.

Answer (score 1):

Whether this is a good design or not depends deeply on what you are trying to represent with it. So, it might be OK or it might not be... there's no way to tell just from your question in its current form.

That being said, there are couple ways to speed up a join:

- Use indexes.
- Use [covering indexes](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index).
- Under the right DBMS, you could use a materialized view to store pre-joined rows. You should be able to simulate that under MySQL by maintaining a special table via triggers (or even manually).
- Don't join a table unless you actually need its fields. List only the fields you need in the SELECT list (instead of blindly using *). The fastest operation is the one you don't have to do!

And above all, **measure** on [representative amounts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14718958/533120) of data! Possible results:

- It's lightning fast. Yay!
- It's slow, but it doesn't matter that it's slow (i.e. rarely used / not important).
- It's slow and it matters that it's slow. Strap-in, you have work to do!

Answer (score 0):

We need Query with 11 joins and the EXPLAIN posted in the original question when it is available, please.   And be kind to your community, for every table involved post as well SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname  SHOW INDEX FROM tblname to avoid additional requests for these 11 tables.  And we will know scope of data and cardinality involved for each indexed column.

Answer (score -1):

of Course more join kills performance.
but it depends !! if your data model is like that then you can't help yourself here unless complete new data model re-design happen !!

1) is it a online(real time transaction ) DB or offline DB (data warehouse)

if online , then better maintain single table. keep data in one table , let column increase in size.!!

if offline , it's better to maintain separate table , because you are not going to required all column always.!!

Comment: More joins doesn't kill performance. RDBMSs love joins. Functions, and an absence of indexes kills (select query) performace.

Comment: my bad i forgot to mention index. as i thought everything included (whether index,partition..etc). RDBMS loves joins !!! as i mentioned it depends on data volume, type..etc !!